# Padding in select tag doesn't work in Safari

Tags: safari, cross-browser

I want a `padding` of `10px` on my `select` tag. With a text-indent I can make the `padding-left` work on Safari. But I want a padding everything not just left.

Is there any way to have it work normally on Safari? (I can't understand how something so elemental can be an issue nowadays!)

Comment: Please post HTML and CSS for us, if you can use http://jsfiddle.net to  illustrate issue.

Comment: _“I can't understand how something so elemental can be an issue nowadays!”_ – form controls are a bit “special”, because they are not always rendered by the browser alone, but by the OS sometimes – so formatting possibilities might be limited. And another issue for some browser vendors to limit formatting of such elements is to preserve the look-and-feel that the user already knows.

Answer (score 0):

try `-webkit-padding:`....that should work. here's Apple's list of properties that safari supports...I don't see any differentiation between safari and mobile safari, but I know there is some...https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html